# How to return the Max value of a select statement

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

Okay so to what I am trying to do is return the max value of a select statement

The statement is written as

```
SELECT 
    SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*[Order Details].Quantity) as total, 
    Products.SupplierID
 FROM [Order Details], Products GROUP By Products.SupplierID;
```

which is returning a list of values with a of that each supplier is making in revenue from sales.

When I change the statement to

```
SELECT 
    MAX([Order Details].UnitPrice*[Order Details].Quantity) as total, 
    Products.SupplierID
 FROM [Order Details], Products GROUP By Products.SupplierID;
```

it returns the same value for each supplier which isn't what I want I just want the statement to return the SupplierID that has the highest revenue.

I will note that this is an assignment but it isn't the whole thing

*The assignment reads*

Among all the suppliers listed in your Northwind database, find the one with the highest total revenue based on all the orders in the database.

Write a user-defined scalar function MaxSupplier that outputs a single value: the name of the supplier selected according to the above-mentioned rule. If more than one supplier qualifies, select a random one among such candidates. You may need to research the functions available on SQL Server.

Honestly just want to know how to get the max value don't care for help on the rest of the assignment

Comment: Please learn how to join tables! One tip to remember is to DO NOT USE COMMAS between table names. Your results will be wrong  because you have multiplied EVERY row of the 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest solution here would be to use `TOP` with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Products.SupplierID
    SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*[Order Details].Quantity) AS total
FROM [Order Details], Products
GROUP BY
    Products.SupplierID
ORDER BY
    total DESC;
```

If you are using a version of SQL Server earlier than 2008, then you would have to repeat the full sum expression in the `ORDER BY` clause.  If you want to also return all records tied with the highest total, then use this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
```

One other note is that it appears you are doing a cross join between your two tables.  If this is not intended, then use an explicit join with an `ON` condition instead.